# MySql связи между таблицами ползователей локасии и статусом

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Добрый ночи всем.
На базе данных MYSQL, надо реализовать связи между 3мя таблицами
1. Пользователи, 2. Статус, 3. Локация.

1. Пользователи
   user_id int primary key
   stat_id int
   loc_id int
2. Статус
   stat_id int Primary key
   status vArchar(50) //тут храница 3 вида статуса
3. Локация
   loc_id int primary key
   location varchar(70) //тут храница названия городов

проблема в том что при связки таблиц msql выдаёт ошибку: №1215-Невозможно добавить ограничения внешнего ключа!
Как сделать связ правильно?

Comment: Структуры дайте в форме CREATE TABLE. Запрос на создание внешнего ключа и сообщение об ошибке - цитатой.

Comment: если задать всё через код можно избежать выхода такой ошибки?

Comment: Можно, если устранить причину. Их всего 5, см http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/30.html

Comment: Спасибо помогло!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверь тип данных во всех таблицах, при связи должны быть полностью одинаковые типы данных

Comment: Я проверил и оказалось что не задал индексов, спасибо!